# Git: Checkout older commit keeps many current files/folders

Tags: android, git, macos, checkout

I'm not finding any related question, that's why I ask.

I'm working on an Android app with Android Studio on Mac and needed to recover previous versions of the app that weren't tagged. For that I identified the corresponding commit hashes and did git checkout <commit_hash>, but the problem is that a lot of current version folders (that did not exist in that older version and are indeed commited) are kept and still visible when you do ls on a terminal, what I think it's not normal.

I'd like to know if this is really normal or if I am missing any git parameter to avoid this behaviour.

I have to add that folders are mostly empty, with only few java files -like buildconfig.java- inside, but anyway I don't want to mix files from a version into another one.

I could just delete them, but in an Android app there are hundreads of folders and files, and it would be impossible to identify them.

Comment: `git clean -fd` -f force deletion of files wtthout confirmation. -d delete directories.

Comment: Start with `git clean -nd` (-n for dry-run) to check you won't throw away files you should keep

Comment: Thank you @LeGEC. Even using - n parameter is it safe to do this? I mean, an Android Studio project has hundreds of files you don't even know they exist, then you really don't know whether you should keep them or not. I tried a git clean -fd (on a backup folder) and the app compiles and runs fine, but... can I be really sure I can go on with this even when the app compiles? Can I be sure I won't lost any important file even if I don't know what is it exactly for?

Comment: Any of you, please write is as an answer so I can accept it